# How can I resolve "unexpected EOF" error when pulling docker image

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose

I have Docker Desktop 4.16.2 (95914) on MacOS Ventura 13.1, and as far as I know I'm not connected to any proxies. I've authenticated to docker hub via docker desktop, and have tried to pull a python base image by running "docker build .", with the following line at the top of the Dockerfile:

FROM python:3

I get the following error:

```
Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": unexpected EOF
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this and how to resolve it?

Comment: You don't need to authenticate to docker hub in order to do `docker pull`. Can you log out and try again, to see if successful ?

Comment: @Philippe no that didn't work either.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same error with this version of Docker for Desktop. The only difference is I run Mac OS Monterey 12.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pinned down the issue to privileges changes since Docker Desktop 4.15.0 for Mac.

What fixed the issue on my end was to downgrade to 4.14.1:

1. Uninstall Docker completely. This can be done by opening Docker Desktop UI, clicking the Bug icon and clicking "Uninstall". Then, the application can be moved to the bin.
2. Install [Docker Desktop 4.14.1](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4141)

I encountered this issue on a company Mac where I suspect the Privileges app I need to use to elevate permissions doesn't work well with the privileges changes Docker made starting from 4.15.0.
Extract from their [4.15.0 changelog](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4150):

> Docker Desktop for Mac no longer needs to install the privileged helper process com.docker.vmnetd on install or on the first run. For more information see [Permission requirements for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/permission-requirements/).